# WPF UI is not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have developed a simple wpf application using MVVM model and code as below.I debug the code and found that collection is updating but UI is not updating even I don't see any record in listbox.

**EDIT**

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="Model.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="WPF Dispatcher Demo" Height="350" Width="525">


    <DockPanel>
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" Name="col0" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding ShowPath}" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                  Margin="30" Grid.Column="0" />
            <Button Name="FindButton" Content="Select Path" 
              Width="100" Margin="20" Click="FindButton_Click" Grid.Column="1" />
        </Grid>
        <ListBox Name="listBox1"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Files}"/>


    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

**Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;


namespace Model
{
    public class DirectorySearchModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<string> _files = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        private string _showPath;
        public DirectorySearchModel() { }
        void ShowCurrentPath(string path)
        {
            ShowPath = path;
        }


        void AddFileToCollection(string file)
        {
            _files.Add(file);
        }
        public void Search(string path, string pattern)
        {

            if (System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
                ShowPath = path;
            else
                System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                  new Action<string>(ShowCurrentPath), DispatcherPriority.Background, new string[] { path }
                );
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern);
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                if (System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
                    Files.Add(file);
                else
                    System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action<string>(AddFileToCollection), DispatcherPriority.Background,
                      new string[] { file }
                    );
            }
            string[] dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path);
            foreach (string dir in dirs)
                Search(dir, pattern);
        }

        public string ShowPath
        {
            get
            {
                return _showPath;
            }
            set
            {
                _showPath = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ShowPath");
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<string> Files
        {
            get
            {
                return _files;
            }
            set
            {
                _files = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Files");
            }
        }
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

MainWindow.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Model
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        IAsyncResult cbResult;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);

        }
        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DataContext = new DirectorySearchModel().Files;
        }

        private void FindButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            dlg.SelectedPath = path;
            DialogResult result = dlg.ShowDialog();
            if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                path = dlg.SelectedPath;
                string pattern = "*.*";
                new Model.DirectorySearchModel().Search(path, pattern);
                Action<string, string> proc = new Model.DirectorySearchModel().Search;
                cbResult = proc.BeginInvoke(path, pattern, null, null);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I copied your code and found something interesting about it. Sorry for staring blind.

Comment: @Silvermind:Code is working now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In WPF, there are two layers: the UI layer and the Data Layer

The Data Layer is your `DataContext`, and when you write a normal binding, you are binding to the `DataContext`.

When you write

```
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.DataContext = new DirectorySearchModel().Files;
}
```

you are telling WPF that the data layer for the form is going to be an ObservableCollection of strings, however `ObservableCollection<string>` does not have a property called `Files`, so your ListBox binding is failing.

```
<!-- Trying to bind to DirectorySearchModel.Files.Files -->
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Files}"/>
```

You need to change your data layer to your `DirectorySearchModel` instead, so the binding correctly evaluates to `DirectorySearchModel.Files`

```
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.DataContext = new DirectorySearchModel();
}
```

But this isn't your only problem. Your Button's Click event operates on a *new* instance of `DirectorySearchModel` instead of the existing one.

You could simply use `(DirectorySearchModel)MainWindow.DataContext`, but this isn't ideal because it tightly combines your UI and your data layers closely together, and it makes the assumption that the `DataContext` will always be of type `DirectorySearchModel`.

You could store the `DirectorySearchModel` used for the `DataContext` somewhere like [moncadad suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16045387/302677) so you can access it from somewhere else in your code:

```
DirectorySearchModel _model = new DirectorySearchModel();
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _model = new DirectorySearchModel();
    this.DataContext = _model ;
}

private void FindButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // use _model instead of "new DirectorySearchModel()" here
}
```

But honestly this still isn't ideal because your View and your Data layers are still tightly coupled together, and this isn't compliant with the MVVM design pattern (which you've tagged your question with, so I'm assuming you're using).

The best solution is to actually replace your button's Click event with an `ICommand` on the `DirectorySearchModel` so you don't have to worry about storing and accessing a copy of your data layer from your UI layer. This also has the added benefit of keeping application logic inside the application layer, instead of mixing it in with the UI layer:

```
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.DataContext = new DirectorySearchModel();
}

<DockPanel>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" Name="col0" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBox Text="{Binding ShowPath}" ... />

        <Button Content="Select Path" Command="FindButtonCommand" ... />
    </Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Files}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

This correctly separates your UI from your Data layer, which is the primary goal of the MVVM design pattern.

This way, your application logic all stays inside your application objects, while your UI becomes just a pretty user-friendly interface that is used to interact with your application objects.

I like to write beginner WPF articles, and I'd suggest reading my post [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/) to understand what the `DataContext` is and how it works a bit better :)

Comment: this is the detailed answer @geek! nice one @Rachel.

Answer (score 2):

You have:
    `this.DataContext = new DirectorySearchModel().Files;`

and this:
    `<ListBox Name="listBox1"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Files}"/>`

Which means it will try to bind to DirectorySearchModel().Files.Files.  You probably want to change to this: `this.DataContext = new DirectorySearchModel();`

Comment: @NTyler Also, if he's using the ListBox as input, he should enable Two-Way Binding Mode, since [ItemsControl.ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) defaults to One-Way Binding Mode.

Comment: @Bob Why should it be two-way? It's not common to update a collection property. More common is to update the contents of a collection and that is beyond the two-way binding.

Comment: @Bob. the source that is specified on one way comes from the viewmodel dude and not from the list box. so there is no need to specify it.

Comment: @Bob:I tried Tow-Way binding also ,but it's still not updating the UO

Comment: @geek What part "isn't working" after changing the `DataContext` to the `DirectorySearchModel()` instead of `DirectorySearchModel().Files`? If it's your `GetFiles()` command, then it's probably because you're operating on a different `DirectorySearchModel` object than the one you have set as your DataContext

Comment: @Rachel: Listbox is not showing any record after making all these changes

Comment: @Rachel great point out that he is adding the files on a new viewmodel and not on the current datacontext.. LIKE!

Comment: @geek are you sure that you're making changes to the correct DirectorySearchModel object?  You've checked mainWindow.DataContext and that is showing all of your changes?

Answer (score 2):

** Edit **

I was staring blind :)

You're not reusing your model:
This works, I just tested it

```
    private DirectorySearchModel model = new DirectorySearchModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);

    }
    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataContext = model; //The model is already available as private member
    }

    private void FindButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        dlg.SelectedPath = path;
        DialogResult result = dlg.ShowDialog();
        if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            path = dlg.SelectedPath;
            string pattern = "*.*";
            Action<string, string> proc = model.Search; // use existing model (the private member).
            cbResult = proc.BeginInvoke(path, pattern, null, null);

        }
    }
```

In Xaml put this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Files}"/>
```

Comment: @geek, Are you positive that the collection has items when you debug it?

Comment: :I have attached the snapshot of debug window

Comment: @geek, it's strange. Could you take a look at the output window and check if there are any binding error messages?

Comment: Its far better to simply set the property you need instead of binding the `DataContext` the way you have for your `ListBox` binding. For example, `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Files}" />`. This way, if you need to bind any of the other properties on the element, you can easily do so. (It's also easier to maintain and debug, since people expect the `DataContext` to be inherited instead of specifically set for every object)

Comment: @Rachel You're right. That got stuck in revising my first analysis. I was trying something else ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your MainWindow.cs, change to:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    IAsyncResult cbResult;
    DirectorySearchModel _model = new DirectorySearchModel();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = _model;
    }
...
```

In your Xaml, update your binding to:

```
<ListBox Name="listBox1"  ItemsSource="{Binding Files, UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"}"/>
```

Comment: Isn't `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` the default behavior?

Comment: @NTyler Ah, you are correct. "The default value for most dependency properties is PropertyChanged, while the Text property has a default value of LostFocus."

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the DataContext of your window to a new instance of DirectorySearchModel. it is not updating because your ListBox inherited the DataContext of the window which is set to the Files property. Your listbox is looking for the Files Property of the Files Collection which does not exists.

You can use this Code

```
public MainWindow()
{
   this.DataContext = new DirectorySearchModel();
}
```

this way your list box will have a datacontext of a new directory search model and will be looking for the Files property which you had specify on the **Path** property of the ItemSource Binding.

UPDATE:

```
    private void FindButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        dlg.SelectedPath = path;
        DialogResult result = dlg.ShowDialog();
        if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            path = dlg.SelectedPath;
            string pattern = "*.*";
            //OLD CODE                
            //new Model.DirectorySearchModel().Search(path, pattern);
            //SUGGESTION
            (this.DataContext AS DirectorySearchModel).Search(path, pattern);
            Action<string, string> proc = (this.DataContext AS DirectorySearchModel).Search;
            cbResult = proc.BeginInvoke(path, pattern, null, null);

        }
    }
```

Comment: It's updating or not updating? if it's updating, isn't that what you like?

Comment: Hey @geek check my update, I think you are storing the file contents on new object instead of the current datacontext.

Comment: Now it's showing the record but it's not updating the UI continuously

Comment: @geek what do you mean on "continously"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28330/discussion-between-allan-chua-and-geek)